# How to import a node_module package in client

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I was using CDN but needed some changes in the code so I install the npm package but dont know how to imported in my client view.

I tried:

```js
import Calendar from './@event-calendar/core';

import TimeGrid from './@event-calendar/time-grid';
```

And also

```js
import * as Calendar from './@event-calendar/core';

import * as TimeGrid from './@event-calendar/time-grid';
```

But I get error:

> "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

Here is a [Screen shot of my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHkuP.png)

And here of the [node modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z17ZN.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this line

```
<script type=“module” src=“some-url”></script>
```

Comment: require cannot be used in client side

Comment: Sorry my bad, I updated the solution, can you take a look?

Comment: what should I put on url? I tried that but maybe am noy putting the src correctly

Comment: Try to use full path (./node_modules/<path>).
Also try to use [Browserify](https://linuxhint.com/run-nodejs-module-browser/)